# Detect strange behavior of AppEngine Flexible Java (Deployed but it 's not restart the new deployed version)

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I observed this strange behavior for 2 weeks. (15 June 2019) Normally, when I deploy my java-web app on Google App Engine Flexible , it will restart the instance with new app version.

But right now, after **mvn appengine:deploy**  finish its process.  The new deployed web app version is not active automatically.  I need to find the way to stop the instance and start the instance manually.   Normally, App Engine will manage this automatically when I saw this log

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: Updating service [my-service] (this may take several minutes)...
```

I've used the latest update of gcloud sdk.  So don't know where the bug is coming from. I didn't change anything from my side.  This is what I observed.

Please suggest thanks,  :)

Didn't change any configuration,  Just update the business logic of my code and re-deploy with **mvn appengine:deploy**.   But after the deployment successful, it's not automatically active the newly deployed version.

Comment: As of 7 July 2019,   after mvn appengine:deploy  (and automaticaclly update the SDK)   the way to deploy AppEngine Flexible is perfect like before. No issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [App Engine Maven Plugin (Cloud SDK-based) Goals and Parameters](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven-reference#goal_parameters) documentation, it is stated that you need this following line in the **pom.xml** file.

```
  <deploy.stopPreviousVersion>true</deploy.stopPreviousVersion>
```

It should stop only your previous serving version while deploying the new one. In case you have more than one previous versions serving, you have to stop them manually.

I’ve reproduced your use-case scenario and it worked for me. I deployed version 1, then I deployed version 2, and the version 1 stopped serving while all the traffic was allocated to version 2.

If this is not helpful, please update your question's description and share the exact reproduction steps.

Comment: Yes, but I use this property (stopPreviousVersion) since year 2015 and still using it.   But the strange behavior in my case right now it's disappeared , I didn't do anything. Just update the gcloud sdk to the latest version automatically.  Problem solved.